# stylesheet_link_tag get all stylesheets but one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application which in my layout I have

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

But I want it to load all my css file except one. Is it possible to do that? Get all my .css file but one in specific I want to deny.

Comment: Why do you want to deny it? Are you loading it in another template?

Comment: Can you, please, elaborate more? Do you want to not require one css file on the manifest on certain views? or never load? please, post your manifest `application.css` and the file you want to skip.

Comment: The file I want to deny actually is bootstrap.css. Because on the "main application" of the web app I can get bootstrap's css through their cdn (over the web). But some pages of this web app will also be loaded inside a Mikro Tik hotspot, which blocks not specified urls. So these pages I have to access inside my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that like this in your `application.css`

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*= stub css_want_to_exclude
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `application.css`, where you have:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

You just need to remove the `require_tree` directive, that loads all stylesheets in the css folder, and require them manually. So you'll have something like this:

```
*= require lib1
*= require lib2
*= require lib3
*= require lib4
*= require_self
```